# Revealing a UL on click in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some problems and hoping you could help.

I have the following HTML code

```
<h4><a class="trigger">Click </a></h4>

<ul class="panel">
<li>List items bla bla bla </li>
<li>List items bla bla bla </li>
<li>List items bla bla bla </li>
</ul>

<h4><a class="trigger">Click </a></h4>

<ul class="panel">
<li>List items bla bla bla </li>
<li>List items bla bla bla </li>
<li>List items bla bla bla </li>
</ul>
```

And I would like that on click it toggles. I have the following code in jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('ul.panel').hide();
    $("a.trigger").click(function(){
        $("ul.panel").slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now I know it won't work because it's selecting ALL items. How can I use it so it only toggles the actual trigger that was clicked and not toggle all of them? I have tried to use FIND, SIBLINGS, NEXT, etc but I can't.

Any help, appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a.trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('h4').next('.panel').slideToggle();
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/nQCJk/)

The concept here is that you traverse the DOM to get to a common point where you can generalize your commands. In my example, I navigate outward to a common ancestor (`h4`) and then find the next list *relative to that parent element*. If you have a templated layout, this is a very common technique for DOM traversal.

Comment: This does the job, however for some odd reason when it toggles it goes to the upper part of the document. As opposed to staying confined within the h4 element. ANy ideas?

Comment: unfortunately, that's outside of the scope of the code you provided. that's probably a CSS issue, but you have provided no CSS.

Comment: I dont know what the hell is going on, but when I replaced my line of code that does the toggling with yours, it worked..lol. Originally I just copied/pasted it.


Edit: it's the return false... if I add it, it doesn't do that.
Thanks Jason!!!